# Extending styled components properties?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

H1.js

```
export default styled.h1`
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
`;
```

I want to change the color of this component, and I tried

```
import H1 from "./H1";

const ColoredH1 = styled(H1)`
    color: "black"
`;
```

But this is not changing the color of the H1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `"black"` **with quotes**, remember that you write CSS within the `styled-component`, therefore "black" isn't a valid color, although `black` do.

```
const ColoredH1 = styled(H1)`
  /* color: "black"; */  /* Invalid Color */

  color: black;          /* Valid Color */
  color: ${"black"}      /* Or use a valid color representation as String */
`;
```

[image: Edit Q-58577335-SyledString]

Comment: styled.h1`` color: "black" `` works from a reason you don't expect, as said "black" isn't a valid color, **so it didn't override the default value which is `black`**, try "yellow" and see the differences

Comment: Yeah I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put `color: black` instead of `color: "black"`

```
import H1 from "./H1";

const ColoredH1 = styled(H1)`
    color: black;
`;
```

For your understanding

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: red;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

const CoralButton = styled(Button)`
  color: coral;
  border-color: coral;
`;
render(
  <div>
    <Button>Normal Button</Button>
    <CoralButton>Tomato Button</CoralButton>
  </div>
);
```